# WordPress Fatal Error - Memory Usage

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I was wondering if someone could suggest a way around the dreaded WP fatal error of memory usage.

I have around 10,000 pages and had no issue at 8000. It's only the back end > pages that is giving the error.

Is there anyway of optimizing the database or something else?

Comment: Contact WordPress support for this.

Comment: It will be very useful to know what kind of error you have and your server configuration !

Comment: @Benoti it is the memory usage error. the wp_posts table is 300+ mib. The issue can be fixed by adding more memory but it doesn't solve the slow backend issue

Comment: @Matthew : what is the error exactly ? $wpdb ? or mysql ?

Comment: @benoti could you explain how this helps when I am receiving the memory limit error?

Comment: its wp-db.php @Benoti

Answer (score 2):

To increase memory you can do it with wp-config.php.

Administration tasks require much memory than usual operation. When in the administration area, the memory can be increased or decreased from the `WP_MEMORY_LIMIT` by defining `WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT`.

```
define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M' );

define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
```

note, this has to be put before wp-settings.php inclusion.

With php.ini

```
memory_limit = 256M ;
```

With .htaccess

```
php_value memory_limit 256M
```

It could be great to upgrade some other values like `set_time_limit` (that returns error when reached) and `max_execution_time`